How do threads aid in execution of a program?
Firstly this is not a question about programming. A book I am reading on C programming explains briefly the steps of execution of a C program after its compilation. It states the following,

To be precise, operating system do not only create a process and allocate the memory to it for keeping text, data and all resources required for execution, but it also creates a thread for the execution of the program. The thread is defined as lightweight process and is responsible for the execution of the program. In fact, the stack section belongs to the thread and gets space into process memory. The thread created by the operating system for the execution of the program is called as main thread or primary thread. In some complicated programs, one can create multiple threads using native (operating system specific) library for efficient and concurrent program execution on uni-processor systems.

Questions:

What is meant by 'Operating system also creates a thread for the execution of the program'? How do threads aid in execution of the program? What do threads actually do? ChatGPT provided the association that threads are like workers in a workspace (memory) which aid in execution of a project (program).

Does a process have stack of its own or its comprised only of stacks of its threads? OR Does a process and its thread have a separate stack section in memory?

Is main or the primary thread the only thread in execution of a program that is supposed to be uni-threaded?


Also, are there concise resources or books that will help me get a hang of this topic?

You seem to ask for another introduction of the term thread (of program execution), one that is more useful to you. In How do threads aid in execution of the program?, are you asking What advantage is there to having more than one thread??

@greybeard no i’m merely asking how’s it accomplished, concisely.

Anything from ChatGPT you better remove from your brain instantly. It's worse then clueless. It provides sentences that roughly resemble answers made with highest confidence, without any understanding whether what it says has anything to do with reality or not.
